# Cocoa Bindings or code?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings

I was wondering which way would be better if I were making a simple application with a table view in it.  Cocoa bindings seem much simpler but it meet take up more CPU or RAM, which is why I'm asking the experts for some opinions about the 2 ways.  Thanks.

Comment: As a general rule, do what's most sensible first, then optimize later if you even need to. So, use bindings; they're wonderful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bindings.

Why manage it all yourself and worry about performance without profiling?

Machines are pretty fast these days, and worrying about whether there is an unacceptable overhead with using Bindings in a *simple application* (as you call it) is just being silly.

Comment: Yeah I know, but what if I start doing BIG projects later or high CPU usage apps?  Would it affect the app?

Comment: Bindings is just a light wrapper around KVO, which you would have to do anyway. I'd use Bindings for Big and intensive programs in the first place, then profile to find bottlenecks that can be improved on. I'm almost willing to take bets that the code you write will be less efficient than any overhead introduced by using Bindings.

Comment: Thanks.  It probably would be a good idea to use cocoa bindings in big projects as it would result in less code.